# Broadcast different controllers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, broadcast, angularjs-service

I am developing a permission system for my app using a factory that looks like this:

```
angular.module('ecosystemServices', [])
.factory('Guard', function($http, $rootScope) {
    var permissions = [];
    return {

        ready: function() {
            if (permissions.length == 0) {
                $http.get('/api/users/own-permissions')
                    .success(function(data){
                        permissions = data.user_permissions;
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('permissionsReady', 1);
                });
            } else {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('permissionsReady', 1);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
})
```

I have to wait until the permissions are loaded to start making queries, so I'm performing a broadcast to the controller, that looks something like this:

```
appControllers.controller('AgencyPanelCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', '$http','Guard',
function ($rootScope, $scope, $location, $routeParams, $http, Guard) {

    $scope.loading = true;


    Guard.ready();

    $scope.has_permission = function(permission) {
        return Guard.can(permission);
    }

    $rootScope.$on('permissionsReady', function(event, ready) {
        $scope.initialize();
    });


    $scope.initialize = function() {
        console.log("Initialized");
    }

}]);
```

It's working, but if I change the controller and do the same (change the view and change the controller), the broadcast arrives to the old controller.

Does anyone knows why? Or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your event listener on the `$rootScope`. As the name would suggest, there is only one `$rootScope`, and it's at the root of the document.

As such, when your view changes and the old controller is no longer relevant, the `$rootScope` still has the listener, which still holds a reference to the old controller's `$scope` through a closure, and hence everything still goes to the old controller.

Instead, you should define the listener on the `$scope` of the controller:

```
$scope.$on('permissionsReady', function(event, ready) {
    $scope.initialize();
});
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Right, I made that now. Now it doesn't broadcast to the old controller, but it doesn't broadcast at all (the broadcast line is executed but it does not arrive at the $on closure. It works for the first time, though, but only once. After that, it doesn't matter if I go back to the view that worked for the first time, it doesn't work anymore unless I reload the page

Comment: It does broadcast, but something needs to listen to it. If this controller isn't active, then nothing is listening... do you have another listener defined elsewhere?

Comment: The second controller is very similar and also have the $on piece of code. Should I do something more than that? When I instantiate the second controller, the first line (before $on) is the call that triggers the broadcast. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I changed the order (setting the call that triggers the broadcast before the $on method and it works). I give you the right answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to set up a listener to the event before the event is triggered to ensure your listener receives it. What is happening is your broadcast is firing straight away (before the line that registers the listener is called), so by the time you register that listener it's too late. This isn't a problem for the first controller, because you don't have the permissions from the server, so there is a delay.

Comment: No problem - make sure you also switch the order in the first controller too, in case you come back to it and you already have the permissions cached.